# jump to a certain file in emacs dired

Tags: emacs

I wonder how can I jump to a certain file or folder in emacs in dired mode?

Lets say I enter a folder with hundreds of files and folders, and I know the file I want is about at the middle of the list since it starts with the "G", for example.

Is there a command to make the caret go directly to the first file/folder that starts with "G" so I can narrow my search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously just use `isearch`, but there is a built in function that is better.

```
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(progn
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-s") 'dired-isearch-filenames)
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-M-s") 'dired-isearch-filenames-regexp)
))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! Even you gave me the way to bind it nicely!

Comment: I've edited the post.  I forgot to quote the body of `eval-after-load`.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using `dired-jump`

```
(autoload 'dired-jump "dired-x" "Jump to dired corresponding current buffer.")
(autoload 'dired-jump-other-window "dired-x" "jump to dired in other window.")
```

Then call:

```
M-x dired-jump
```

or

```
M-x dired-jump-other-window
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want to jump to the name of the file in the dired buffer and not actually open the file itself.  For this you can just search for the file name using isearch:

```
C-s G...
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the first thing I tried. If I isearch, for example, "dr" then the place where the caret will go is to the file permissions column `drwxr-xr-` :(